# Sobreescritura de bytes, borrado totalmente seguro?

Tags: seguridad

No estoy seguro de que, sobreescribir un archivo con bytes aleatorios y luego eliminarlo, sea suficiente para considerar el archivo eliminado totalmente.
Hay alguna posibilidad de recuperarlo?
Y también, si formateo un pendrive, lo lleno hasta el ultimo byte con datos aleatorios y luego formatearlo de nuevo, tengo la absoluta seguridad de que es imposible recuperar nada?
Muchas gracias